# Heap overflow detection/prevention in embedded systems

Tags: c, embedded

I've been bitten a few times recently by overrunning the heap on embedded systems.

This usually occurs due to writing to arrays declared on the heap past the array's size, which must overrun other heap declared variables and then cause very undefined behaviour - making the root cause hard to track down.

Are there any methods for detecting/preventing these sort of heap overrun errors on embedded systems? I'm developing for a STM32 platform, but would be happy to know of any general approaches. I'd be happy to hear of approaches that find overrun at runtime or static analysis approaches that can find overrun before compilation.

Note that because this is code running on embedded systems, the use of `malloc` is rare - most heap variables are statically or globally declared without the use of `malloc`.

Comment: What do you mean by "on the heap" ?  The normal meaning in CS of that term is dynamic storage allocated from a pool by memory allocation functions -- which, assuming the allocator is not bugged, will either return valid storage or a null pointer.  It's not possible to "declare on the heap".

Comment: Code review / assertions / testing.

Comment: @M.M either global variables or variables declared in function scopes as `static`.

Comment: Those are static variables  , they have nothing to do with the heap

Comment: anyway: design your code so that any function that writes to memory takes enough parameters to know where the end of allocated memory is, and make your code simple and clear so that it is easy to do code review and spot if a function might write past the end.  If a function is too big to get your head around it then use smaller functions. You could use a test framework to be able to test each function individually.

Comment: @M.M thanks for clearing that up, I was under the impression if I declare `static char array[50]` within a function scope, it will be allocated on the heap. Is this incorrect?

Comment: That's not the usual meaning of "the heap", no.  The term isn't used by the C Standard, but it's commonly used in computer science to mean space that can be allocated, freed, reallocated etc. from a pool, because the type of tree data structure used to manage space within the pool was called a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure))

Comment: Ah, right. I think I might be confusing my terminology. Would it be correct to say that the statically declared array lives in the "data section" of memory? I was thinking that data section and heap were synonymous, my bad.

Comment: The Standard C term is "static" , there are various other implementation-specific terms floating around such as "data section"

Comment: umm_malloc is designed for embedded and you have full control of you memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was hanging in with your question until you got to the last paragraph and there seems to be some confusion over just what you are calling "heap". So I'm going to assume that most of your problems occur when accessing memory outside the bounds of an array regardless of where the memory for the array actually resides.

Here's what I usually try to do:

1. Never use malloc. It's usually not done in embedded micro-controller code. Whether or not that is a good or bad thing is a judgement matter. Opinions vary, but I just stay away from it. Worst case allocation can waste some memory, but generally I find that reasonable bounds for array sizes can be found for applications targeted for micro-controllers.
2. Try to separate the system specific from the platform independent. This is particularly true for access to hardware and such. Don't do it directly; use some hardware layer that, these days, is usually supplied by the chip manufacturer.
3. For the platform independent parts, you can now stub out the system specific portions and compile the code on to run on a desktop. There you can have access to all kinds of tools to analyze what's going on. You can get access to static analyzers that just won't run on a micro-controller. You can also do better code coverage analysis and more testing is easier to automate. You potentially can have problems with portability between the desktop and micro-controller, but I have not found that to be a big problem. Careful, portable coding is the key.

Now this is more work, of course, and it certainly helps to have started the project with these ideas in mind. But over the years I have found it easier to try to run the embedded code in an environment where I can bring to bear better tooling than to try to improve the embedded environment itself.

Answer (score 0):

Malloc's can overflow heap usage, even sparing use can lead to memory fragmentation, but your test code should be able to detect out of memory errors. Recursive function calls passing by reference can overflow stack usage. If you initialize the entire stack/heap with a set value, you can then scan them to see how much has been used during a test (e.g. fill with 0x3F, post test look for how much of this is 'corrupted'). Set up test cases that maximize the usage to gain confidence that it won't overflow.

1) If memory is plentiful, expand the size of your stack/heap.

2) If memory is tight, consider only static allocation, and don't use library functions that malloc. Reduce function depth and avoid recursion. Consider pushing larger local function variables to globals.

Answer (score 0):

I agree dont use malloc at all of possible on a microcontroller.  As much as everyone says not to, globals are fixed in size and you know at compile time what your usage is.  Local variables and functions are the killer on an extremely memory limited platform, so you really have to think through every local variable you create and how deeply nested your functions are.  So long as you dont do recursion you should be able to by analysis determine your worst case function nesting paths and then how much stack is consumed.  Global is fixed and known at compile time but can be wasteful if too much and not heavily used by every function.  Local is dynamic and if you dont do your analysis can crash into .data or .bss, adding code to detect that just burns through your very limited flash and limited performance.

You could try a valgrind approach (fill the undeclared part of ram normally heap and stack with a known value watch to see how deep the stack digs into that memory and modifies that ram through normal function nesting) but perhaps different, use the linker script to put a buffer at the top of .data/.bss where heap would normally start, write a known set of values there, have an interrupt do a quick check to see if the top value changes, crash/burn/bail/infinite loop if it does, walk the stack to see how you nested your way there.

Or just use a lot of globals and not have to worry about it.